# In which functional programming function would one grow a set of items?

Tags: functional-programming

Which of the three (if any (please provide an alternative)) would be used to add elements to a list of items?

- Fold
- Map
- Filter

Also; how would items be added? (appended to the end / inserted after working item / other)

Comment: A set has no ends. A set is just a bunch of distinct values with no order.

Comment: What language ? None of the above used to *grow* the list, they're used to fold, map the function over, and filter values of/from the list.

Comment: language agnostic, feel free to use any language as an example.

Comment: Each of these functions takes a set or a sequence of elements, but none of them are used to expand that set or sequence.  Fold yields a single element.  Map yields a set or sequence with the same number of elements.  Filter yields a set or sequence with size less than or equal to its input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"cons" is the low-level operation used in most functional programming languages to construct various data structure including lists. In lispy syntax it looks like this:

```
(cons 0 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 nil))))
```

Visually this is a linked list

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> nil
```

Or perhaps more accurately

```
cons -- cons -- cons -- cons -- nil
  |       |       |       |
  0       1       2       3
```

Of course you could construct various "tree"-like data structures with cons as well.

A tree like structure might look something like this

```
(cons (cons 1 2) (cons 3 4))
```

I.e. Visually:

```
  cons
  /  \
cons cons
/ \   / \
1 2   3 4
```

However most functional programming languages will provide many "higher level" functions for manipulating lists.

For example, in Haskell there's

- Append: (++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
- List comprehension: [foo c | c <- s]
- Cons: (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]  (as Martinho already mentioned)
- And many many [more](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html)

Just to offer a concluding remark, you wouldn't often operate on individual elements in a list in the way that you're probably thinking, this is an imperative mindset. You're more likely to copy the entire structure using a recursive function or something in that line. The compiler/virtual machine is responsible recognizing when the memory can be modified in place and updating pointers etc.

Comment: I don't know about the "in *most* functional programming languages to construct *various* data structure including lists" part. Other than LISPs, all FP languages I know use cons only for lists. Other data structures are constructed with other mechanisms (even though you could still use cons to build them). Oh, wait, LISP uses cons only for lists as well: everything is a list in LISP!

Comment: It's true, as you say in Haskell you're probably more likely to use higher level stuff like abstract data types and so forth. Cons seems to be the closest thing to a generic constructor though. Well, if you accept a tree to be a list of lists, you can construct trees with haskell cons too: [1,2] : [[3, 4]].

Comment: At least, let me put it this way: depending on your point of view the "data structure" is either an API or a memory layout...

Answer (score 2):

A list in functional programming is usually defined as a recursive data structure that is either a special empty value, or is composed of a value (dubbed "head") and another list (dubbed "tail"). In Haskell:

```
-- A* = 1 + A x A*
-- there is a builtin list type:
data [a] = [] | (a : [a])
```

To add an element at the head, you can use "cons": the function that takes a head and a tail, and produces the corresponding list.

```
-- (:) is "cons" in Haskell
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]

x = [1,2,3]   -- this is short for (1:(2:(3:[])))
y = 0 : x     -- y = [0,1,2,3]
```

To add elements at the end, you need to recurse down the list to add it. You can do this easily with a fold.

```
consAtEnd :: a -> [a] -> [a]
consAtEnd x = foldr [x] (:)
    -- this "rebuilds" the whole list with cons,
    -- but uses [x] in the place of []
    -- effectively adding to the end
```

To add elements in the middle, you need to use a similar strategy:

```
consAt :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
consAt n x l = consAtEnd (take n l) ++ drop n l
     -- ++ is the concatenation operator: it joins two lists
     -- into one.
     -- take picks the first n elements of a list
     -- drop picks all but the first n elements of a list
```

Notice that except for insertions at the head, these operations cross the whole list, which may become a performance issue.

Comment: I suspect the syntax I used for the list definition is not proper Haskell. If you know how to fix, can you please edit or show me?